# Ungroup/disaggregate in HIVE

Tags: hive, group-by, aggregate

Is it possible to ungroup a dataset in hive? I don't believe you can lateral view explode an integer.

Current table:

```
event  count
A      3
B      2
```

Result table:

```
event count
A     1
A     1
A     1
B     1
B     1
```

Count column obviously not super important in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `space()` function you can convert `count` to string of spaces with length=count-1, then use `split()` to convert it to array and `explode()` with `lateral view` to generate rows.
Just replace the `a` subquery in my demo with your table.

**Demo:**

```
select a.event, 
       1 as count --calculate count somehow if necessary
from
    (select stack(2,'A',3,'B',2) as (event, count)) a --Replace this subquery with your table name
    lateral view explode(split(space(a.count-1),' ')) s
;
```

**Result:**

```
OK
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       1
B       1
Time taken: 0.814 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a numbers table and use it for disaggregation.

```
--create numbers table
create table if not exists dbname.numbers 
location 'some_hdfs_location' as 
select stack(5,1,2,3,4,5) t as num --increase the number of values as needed

--Disaggregation
select a.event,n.num --or a.cnt
from dbname.agg_table a 
join dbname.numbers n on true
where a.cnt >= n.num and a.cnt <= n.num
```

Answer (score 0):

If number of records to dis aggregate is high and you don't want to hard code it.

Create a udf which will return seq of numbers

```
[prjai@lnx0689 py_ws]$ cat prime_num.py
import sys

    try:
            for line in sys.stdin:
                    num = int(line)
                    for i in range(1, num+1):
                            #print u"i".encode('utf-8')
                            print u"%i".encode('utf-8') %(i)
    except:
            print sys.exc_info()
```

Add python script to hive env

```
hive> add FILE /home/prjai/prvys/py_ws/prime_num.py
```

Create temporary table for above script

```
hive> create temporary table t1 as with t1 as (select transform(10) using 'python prime_num.py' as num1) select * from t1;
```

Your query would be -

```
hive> with t11 as (select 'A' as event, 3 as count) select t11.event,  t11.count from t11, t1 where t11.count>=t1.num1;
```

Hope this helps.